# making multiple incoming calls from PSTN

Tags: sip, voip, freeswitch

I have VoIP test setup that uses a media gateway and a softswitch (YATE). The media gateway converts incoming calls from PSTN on an E1 PRI to SIP INVITEs and send them to the softswitch which forwards the INVITEs to the clients that have registered with it. Is there a opensource/free tool available that will allow me to simulate multiple incoming calls from PSTN on the E1 PRI number(s)? I want something similar to sipp but one which can make multiple E1 calls simultaneously. The E1 PRI has about 24 different numbers. I want to a tool to make as many simultaneous calls preferably from my PC using an E1 card. Is this possible?

Appreciate any help/pointers. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any tools that would be the equivalent of sipp, ISDN testing doesn't get the same effort put into tools as SIP these days. However you could always install Asterisk and use its [Application Gateway Interface](http://www.asterisk.org/docs/asterisk/trunk/applications/agi) (AGI) to script the calls, there are lots of high language wrappers for AGI e.g. [PHP](http://www.asterisk.org/docs/asterisk/trunk/applications/agi), [Ruby](https://github.com/erichmond/ruby-agi) etc.

Of course in order to be able to use Asterisk with an E1 PRI you'll need to get your hands on an [E1 PCI card](http://www.digium.com/en/products/digital/single-span/) which I'm sure you could acquire a clone on eBay or such very cheaply (since it's only for testing cheap shouldn't matter, would advise sticking to Digium cards with Asterisk and ISDN in production).